# Does Visual Studio Code provide intellisense for Javascript without typings?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When using a 3rd party libary installed npm, can I expect Visual Studio Code to provide intellisense for the package even though there is no typings file?

This works in IntelliJ/Webstorm so I think it's possible. However, I cannot tell from the Visual Studio Code documentation whether this is currently supported.

Note: I am looking for intellisense while coding in .ts files, not inside of .html files or elsewhere.

Comment: See if the library is listed in the @types scoped npm package `https://www.npmjs.com/~types`. If it is you can simply add types by `npm install @types/libraryname`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of how typings work. Unfortunately, many libraries do not have typings files.

Comment: You're welcome. In this case you should consider [writing declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for the library. Don't forget to check [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) first.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I cannot tell from the Visual Studio Code documentation whether this is currently supported.

Yes it is. Create a `tsconfig.json` file with `compilerOptions.allowJS` set to true.

More : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_mixed-typescript-and-javascript-projects

Comment: Are you certain this does what you think it does? I believe allowJs compiles .js files from within the project. That's fine but that doesn't provide intellisense for .js files in an ignored directory such as node_modules. Obviously, we don't want to recompile all of the npm modules.